# Android Studio cannot be configured correctly with a multi module project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have cloned a project from GitHub and am trying to configure the Android component with Android Studio and the IDE does not work properly. The Gradle button does not show up, I many references are unresolved, my AVD is not recognized and the android module does not even show up in the project.

I configured all dependencies, tried setting folders are sources, creating new modules, restarting IDE but nothing works. I need Android Studio to actually recognize the project and show me the relevant options. This is a C++ project by the way so I am using the NDK to set it up.

You can see from highlighted areas of the screenshot that the android module does not show up and I can't run the "app" as I normally would. There is only a directory name there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the root of the `organicmaps` githug project:

[image]

There is not a `settings.gradle`, therefore it won't import correctly as a Gradle (multi-module) project in AndroidStudio.

I can see in this folder `organicmaps/android` there is a `build.gradle` and a `gradlew` and a `gradle.properties`, so likely this is the "root" of the AndroidStudio project.

[image]

Try opening this folder as the root of your project.
As in close AndroidStudio and create a new project using the folder: `organicmaps/android` instead of `organicmaps`.

---

Based on your comment.

It works for me, I opened the `android` folder in AndroidStudio and it loads as a Gradle project.

[image]

However it does then fail to sync, you have to comment out the code they have for making a release & create an empty `secure.properties` file, because it wants the release credentials and you don't have them.

[image]

After that, you have code completion and the files on your classpath.
There is still an NDK problem, not in my knowledge [how to deal with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65416523/413127) sorry.

^ Did a bit more exploring. After the above, I went up to the root folder and ran:

`./configure.sh` (Figured it sets stuff up, got it from [here](https://github.com/organicmaps/organicmaps/issues/4332).)

Then found all the instructions in `/docs/`, if you read [/docs/INSTALL.md](https://github.com/organicmaps/organicmaps/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#android-app) it has specific Android instructions, and says to import like I said above.

I then ran

`./gradlew webDebug`

[image]

and we're up and running :-)

Comment: Still does not work unfortunately. I am getting a bunch of errors from files and libraries in other modules that are not available here. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Thanks so much. Far more helpful than the official documentation to be honest.

Comment: no problem :-) always some mystery when first setting up new projects!